# Adding interpolated model data column to field dataset in r

Tags: r, for-loop, interpolation, calibration

I'm trying to compare my model data with field data in r. Field data is at certain depths(1,20,50,75,100,150..). Model data output is not at the same depths and have to be interpolated(linear) and preferably added to a new column in the field data.

I would like to run a for loop on each row of the model data and use the approx function to interpolate data to fit the depths of the field data and add it to the model_chla column. I have extracted the same dates(19 dates) from both data sets, so only interpolation on model depth is necesarry.

```
chla_FIELD         # some of the field data with the empty model column
          date depth  chla model_chla
1   2008-02-21     1  0.06         NA
2   2008-02-21    20  0.05         NA
3   2008-02-21    50  0.03         NA
4   2008-02-27     1  0.08         NA
5   2008-02-27    20  0.04         NA
6   2008-02-27    50  0.03         NA
7   2008-02-27    75  0.03         NA
8   2008-02-27   100  0.01         NA
9   2008-03-07     1  0.07         NA
10  2008-03-07    20  0.05         NA
11  2008-03-07    50  0.03         NA
12  2008-03-07    75  0.02         NA
13  2008-03-07   100  0.02         NA
14  2008-03-07   150  0.01         NA


chla_MODEL          # Some of the model data to be interpolated to field data depths and added to column
             dt depth        chla
766  2008-02-21   1.0  0.22385520
767  2008-02-21   7.5  0.21676594
768  2008-02-21  15.0  0.19189246
769  2008-02-21  25.0  0.15524526
770  2008-02-21  40.0  0.14638090
771  2008-02-21  62.5  0.14301939
772  2008-02-21  87.5  0.14094244
773  2008-02-21 112.5  0.13897014
774  2008-02-21 137.5  0.13680272
775  2008-02-21 162.5  0.13430916
776  2008-02-21 187.5  0.13133907
777  2008-02-21 212.5  0.12757768
778  2008-02-21 237.5  0.12237051
779  2008-02-21 262.5  0.11396441
780  2008-02-21 287.5  0.09206185
856  2008-02-27   1.0  0.24240938
857  2008-02-27   7.5  0.23447734
858  2008-02-27  15.0  0.21238998
859  2008-02-27  25.0  0.15545718
860  2008-02-27  40.0  0.14592259
861  2008-02-27  62.5  0.14171122
862  2008-02-27  87.5  0.13900438
863  2008-02-27 112.5  0.13662824
```

My start is something like this, but I'm new to the approx function and adding data to columns in loops.

```
chla_approx <- function(FieldDATA, ModelDATA)
  
  for (row in FieldDATA) {
  
  }
```

Or is there an easier way to do this?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code assumes that all dates in `chla_FIELD` are present in `chla_MODEL`.

If the dates in the data sets are already of class `"Date"` these two instructions are not needed.

```
chla_FIELD$date <- as.Date(chla_FIELD$date)
chla_MODEL$dt <- as.Date(chla_MODEL$dt)
```

Now `split/apply/combine`.

```
sp_field <- split(chla_FIELD, chla_FIELD$date)
sp_model <- split(chla_MODEL, chla_MODEL$dt)

approx_fun_list <- lapply(sp_model, function(data){
  approxfun(data[["depth"]], data[["chla"]])
})

chla_FIELD <- lapply(names(sp_field), function(nm){
  f <- approx_fun_list[[nm]]
  sp_field[[nm]]$model_chla <- f(sp_field[[nm]]$depth)
  sp_field[[nm]]
})
chla_FIELD <- do.call(rbind, chla_FIELD)
```

Final cleanup.

```
rm(sp_field, sp_model)
```

Comment: Thank you Rui. Just what I was looking for and a simple solution too. Now I got some really nice calibration plots to work on. / Niels

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rui. For the purpose of statistics, if I add a "source" column to both datasets:

```
          date depth  chla source
1   2008-02-21     1  0.06  FIELD
2   2008-02-21    20  0.05  FIELD
3   2008-02-21    50  0.03  FIELD

            dt depth       chla source
766 2008-02-21   1.0 0.22385520  MODEL
767 2008-02-21   7.5 0.21676594  MODEL
768 2008-02-21  15.0 0.19189246  MODEL
769 2008-02-21  25.0 0.15524526  MODEL
770 2008-02-21  40.0 0.14638090  MODEL
771 2008-02-21  62.5 0.14301939  MODEL
```

How do I combine the data in series after the split function? (still interpolating the model chla to match field depths) To get something like this:

```
1   2008-02-21     1  0.06  FIELD
2   2008-02-21    20  0.05  FIELD
3   2008-02-21    50  0.03  FIELD
1   2008-02-21     1  0.06  MODEL
2   2008-02-21    20  0.05  MODEL
3   2008-02-21    50  0.03  MODEL
4   2008-02-27     1  0.08  FIELD
5   2008-02-27    20  0.04  FIELD
6   2008-02-27    50  0.03  FIELD
4   2008-02-27     1  0.08  MODEL
5   2008-02-27    20  0.04  MODEL
6   2008-02-27    50  0.03  MODEL
```

Comment: You combine them with `rbind` or with `do.call(rbind, df_list)`, where `df_list` is a list of data.frames.